# ggplot2, colour, geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

Good afternoon, my name is Thiago and I have a question I could not solve in the questions that were asked about ggplot2 on the site.

I did a boxplot chart that has soil types as factors and as categorical variable the soil texture.

The code is as follows:

```
d.solo<-ggplot(data=dens, aes(x=Textura_do_Solo, y=Densidade))+
geom_boxplot(aes(fill=factor(Tipo_de_Solo)), outlier.color = "black", 
outlier.shape = 16, outlier.alpha = 1)+
xlab("Soil texture")+
ylab("Wood density (kg/m³)")+
ylim(250,700)+
theme_classic()+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", family="serif"))+
theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", family="serif"))+
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(family ="serif" ))+
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(family="serif"))+
theme(legend.position="right", legend.text=element_text(family="serif", 
size=10), legend.title = element_text(family="serif", size=10))+
scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Clay","Medium","Sand"),
               breaks=c(1,2,3))+
guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Type of Soil"))+
scale_fill_manual(labels =c("Neossolo","Cambissolo","Argissolo","Latossolo","Plintossolo","Gleissolo","Espodossolo"), values=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7))
```

[image]

```
d.solo+scale_colour_manual(values = c("yellow4", "yellow1", "green2", 
"forestgreen","blue4", "grey36", "chocolate"))
```

I tried changing the colors of the boxplot boxes for each type soil with the last command, but unfortunately the code does not change anything on the chart.

I also tried to put this same code at the end of the ggplot code, but it did not work either.

I'd like to know if anyone can help me solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Your aesthetic for colour of the inside of the boxplot is fill. The colour assignment should be in your scale_fill_manual call.

Comment: `scale_fill_manual(labels =c("Neossolo","Cambissolo","Argissolo","Latossolo","Plintossolo","Gleissolo","Espodossolo"), values=c("yellow4", "yellow1", "green2", 
"forestgreen","blue4", "grey36", "chocolate"))`